# Unresolved dependency: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16 when "sbt update" in scalding

Tags: scala, sbt, scalding

After getting code from git using `clone https://github.com/twitter/scalding.git` and doing `./sbt update` I get:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
```

And later:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
```

I have removed `~/.sbt` directory, installed latest Scala and cloned repository anew. The problem remains.

My configuration:

```
[dk@localhost scalding]$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

[dk@localhost scalding]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

CentOS 6.5 (Final)
```

What can be possibly wrong with `./sbt update`? Should I install the dependency `hadoop-lzo` separately and set CLASSPATH to install Scalding? Any other solutions?

Here is the complete installation log:

```
[dk@localhost wks]$ cd scalding
[dk@localhost scalding]$ ./sbt update
Downloading sbt launcher for 0.13.0:
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.0/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /home/dk/.sbt/launchers/0.13.0/sbt-launch.jar
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12440kB/229ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.2 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24390kB/150ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dk/wks/scalding/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/project/}scalding-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to /home/dk/wks/scalding/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 10 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] there were 2 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] two warnings found
[info] Set current project to scalding (in build file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-args...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-date...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}maple...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-core...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-json...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-parquet...
[info] Resolving com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/dk/.ivy2/local/com.hadoop.gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Concurrent Maven Repo: tried
[warn]   http://conjars.org/repo/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Clojars Repository: tried
[warn]   http://clojars.org/repo/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Twitter Maven: tried
[warn]   http://maven.twttr.com/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-jdbc...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-avro...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-commons...
[info] Resolving com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/dk/.ivy2/local/com.hadoop.gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Concurrent Maven Repo: tried
[warn]   http://conjars.org/repo/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Clojars Repository: tried
[warn]   http://clojars.org/repo/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[warn] ==== Twitter Maven: tried
[warn]   http://maven.twttr.com/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] Updating {file:/home/dk/wks/scalding/}scalding-repl...
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.8.8 ...
[info] Done updating.
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at 
....
.... many lines of exception stack-trace are skipped ...
....

[error] (scalding-commons/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
[error] (scalding-parquet/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16: not found
[error] Total time: 53 s, completed Feb 14, 2014 4:51:51 PM
[dk@localhost scalding]$ ./sbt update^C
[dk@localhost scalding]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[dk@localhost scalding]$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright
```

Comment: <s>The problem is that you're using CentOS instead of the god blessed Debian</s> Joking apart, that dependency comes from http://maven.twttr.com so make sure it is listed in repositories and is not blocked somehow by your host (e.g. can you open it in a browser?). Having said this, on my system `./sbt update` on a fresh repo runs flawlessly.

Comment: @om-nom-nom The repo is already defined in `project/Build.scala` in the project https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/project/Build.scala#L32 so there must be something different.

Comment: @anton-ashanin you don't need to install Scala to run SBT projects. I'd go as far as to say you should remove it and `sbt console` is your buddy now.

Comment: @anton-ashanin Can you paste the entire `sbt update` output? I'm pretty there's a bit more details on the root cause of the issue you face.

Comment: @om-nom-nom You were right. This happens at my company environment and their it-security blocked access to maven.twttr.com. Debian is my favorite too, but I have to use CentOS as a project requirement. Notwithstanding with Debian at home I have some other installation problems with Scalding that I hope to write about later today.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski Added installation log to my original question

Comment: Could be that you're blocked to access http://maven.twttr.com repository and hence http://maven.twttr.com/com/hadoop/gplcompression/hadoop-lzo/0.4.16/hadoop-lzo-0.4.16.pom? Can you check using your browser and when it's worked `curl` from the command line?

Answer (score 11):

SBT is unable to fetch `com.hadoop.gplcompression#hadoop-lzo;0.4.16`
from `resolvers` defined in your **build.sbt**

Adding *maven.twttr.com*:
`"Twitter Maven Repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com"`
should work.

Comment: This worked for me (it should be marked as the correct answer).

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that would work anymore, use: "https://maven.twttr.com" instead.
(Notice the http**s**)
They changed it in Jan 2018

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Today I got a similar error but in `lein`.
I come through a lot of articles and Jira issue.
All recommend put `https` in URL and tag twitter repository directly.
But this does not help.
Does someone know another way?

list of checked sources.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781028/unresolved-dependency-com-hadoop-gplcompressionhadoop-lzo0-4-16-when-sbt-upd
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1556
```